# Custom SurfaceView versus ActionBar redraw

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-custom-view

My little app has a custom SurfaceView that draws itself. Basically it's the green rectangle that you can zoom and pan with your fingers. But somehow I get optical artifacts when I move the rectangle to the top hitting the ActionBar and then down again. Then this green line under the ActionBar remains and is never redrawn unless the app is exited or paused.

Any idea why this happens?

[image]

Comment: may be view is not refreshed thinking view has not changed ? Did you invalidate the action bar ?

Comment: I only invalidate my own custom view, but not the action bar. The custom view is invalidated on each touch (down, move, up) event because I use that to zoom/pan the image with the green bounding box.

Comment: try doing the Action-bar also to remove the line